# % and non-ASCII characters in headings

Tags: xetex, hyperref

It appears that a % together with some non-ASCII characters on a heading is causing problems for hyperref in xelatex. Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{\%á}
\end{document}
```

It goes through with pdflatex but balks when running under xelatex in a second invocation. The error message is:

```
Runaway argument?
{
! File ended while scanning use of \@@BOOKMARK.
<inserted text> 
            \par
l.3    \begin{document}
```

This is noticed when try to convert a CJK markdown document into LaTeX/PDF using pandoc. See [pandoc-discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pandoc-discuss/zAJh8mDmzyA/4SnuugHiAgAJ).

If this a bug? And suggestions of workaround would be much appreciated.

Comment: Loading `hyperref` with the `unicode` option or loading `bookmark` solves the issue.

Comment: Imho it is a bug. hyperref should in `\HyPsd@SanitizeForOutFile` (in hxetex.def) also take care of the percentchar. You should report it at https://github.com/ho-tex/hyperref/issues.

Comment: @egreg I put it into an edef and inserted this into \section: `\edef\temp{\%á} \section{\temp}` Interestingly, it works until I insert the line `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. Even more interestingly, it works, if I substitute utf8 with latin9. Can  you explain this (shortly)?

Comment: @MaestroGlanz Without `inputenc`, `á` is just a character (or a pair of characters if the file is UTF-8 encoded); with `inputenc` it depends on the encoding: with Latin-9 it is an active character expanding to a character, with UTF-8 the two (active) characters don't survive `\edef`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed a bit your fine example just to make some more comparisons:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex\else\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\fi
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}
\section{\%á}
\section{\%a}
\end{document}
```

When `pdflatex` is used for processing, the `.out` file reads

```
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.1}{\045\341}{}% 1
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.2}{\045a}{}% 2
```

However, using `xelatex` produces

```
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.1}{%á}{}% 1
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.2}{\045a}{}% 2
```

and it is clear that something got wrong. Note that using `lualatex` makes the following `.out` file:

```
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.1}{\045á}{}% 1
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.2}{\045a}{}% 2
```

---

Solutions: either call `\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}` or load `bookmark`. I'd recommend the latter way.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\section{\%á}

\section{\%a}

\end{document}
```

Comment: They both worked, thanks! Here's something which baffles me: while `\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}` works, `\usepackage{hyperref} \hypersetup{unicode=true}` produces the same error.

Comment: @stl It depends on the loading order: with `\hypersetup` the setting is done after setting up bookmarks. Something Heiko should look at.